# Use the `replacen` to replace the string with the original variable

Tags: rust

I tried assigning the original `magazine` variable with the replaced characters, but it doesn't work.

```rust
fn can_construct(ransom_note: String, magazine: String) -> bool {
    let ransom_arr: Vec<char> = ransom_note.chars().collect();
    let mut magazine = magazine.as_str();
    for index in 0..ransom_arr.len() {
        let original_length = &magazine.len();
        let mut new_str = &magazine.replacen(ransom_arr[index], "", 1);
        if &new_str.len() == original_length {
            return false;
        }
        magazine = new_str.as_mut_str();
    }
    true
}
```

I don't understand why it fails.

```
let original_length = &magazine.len();
                       -------------- borrow later used here
let mut new_str = &magazine.replacen(ransom_arr[index], "", 1);
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
...
}
- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement

= note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

---

Given two strings ransomNote and magazine, return true if ransomNote can be constructed by using the letters from magazine and false otherwise.

Each letter in magazine can only be used once in ransomNote.

---

The above are the corresponding rules

Example:

Input: ransomNote = "aa", magazine = "ab"

Output: false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `replacen` returns a new `String` and you're taking and storing a reference to it. The `String` itself will be dropped at the end of the block but you're storing it in a variable that lives for longer than that. You can instead store the `String` value:

```rust
fn can_construct(ransom_note: String, mut magazine: String) -> bool {
    let ransom_arr: Vec<char> = ransom_note.chars().collect();
    for index in 0..ransom_arr.len() {
        let original_length = magazine.len();
        let mut new_str = magazine.replacen(ransom_arr[index], "", 1);
        if new_str.len() == original_length {
            return false;
        }
        magazine = new_str;
    }
    true
}
```

This compiles but since you haven't given example inputs/outputs, I couldn't test to see if it works as you expect.

This can be simplified further using iterators:

```rust
fn can_construct(ransom_note: String, mut magazine: String) -> bool {
    for char in ransom_note.chars() {
        let original_length = magazine.len();
        let mut new_str = magazine.replacen(char, "", 1);
        if new_str.len() == original_length {
            return false;
        }
        magazine = new_str;
    }
    true
}
```

---

Both these solutions are `O(n^2)` as string replace is an `O(n)` operation. If I understand the objective correctly, there's a `O(n)` solution possible using a `HashMap`.

Comment: My idea is to judge whether the length has changed after the replacement, and if there is no change, it means that the character does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the optimization suggestions, I'm learning the algorithm and it's very helpful to me.